# Assign Azure CSP subscriptions to your customers programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I have created an AZURE CSP subscription for a customer. 
 When I log in to the particular customer directory as a partner admin user (Customers -> Click the dropdown for a customer -> Microsoft Azure Management Portal link), I am able to see the subscription. 
 But when I try to login as the admin of the customer domain/directory, I am not able to see it.
When I searched about it, I came across the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/assign-azure-subscriptions

Is there any way to do the step Assign Azure subscriptions to your customers through API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Azure Rest API [Role Assignments - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/create) or [Role Assignments - Create By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/createbyid).

You can see that there is a **Try It** feature in the page but we cannot make it work with an CSP admin, because if we sign in with an CSP admin, the access token will be issued for the CSP admin's tenant rather than customer's tenant by default.

To call Azure rest API, you need an access token for Azure. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).

Here is my sample for your reference:

Get the access token for Azure service in Postman. Sign in with your CSP admin to generate the access token. Remember that you should put the customer's tenant id in **Auth URL**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{custopmer's tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and **Access Token URL**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{custopmer's tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

[image]

Use this access token to assign Azure subscription using [Role Assignments - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/create).

[image]

Comment: Here the client id and the client secret should be of customer tenant or the partner tenant?

Comment: @smootherbug Customer tenant.

Comment: I don't want any intervention from the customer, When he logs in with his credentials, he should be able to see the subscription directly.
And there should not be any work for the partner too. Everything needs to be automated. Is it possible for this scenario. Thanks

Comment: @smootherbug You can create the aad application in customer tenant because you are admin.

Comment: creating the aad application can be done through api ?

Comment: @smootherbug Yes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I tried using the above link, but I was not able to create the app in customer tenant, only able to do in partners tenant
can you please help me with this

Comment: @smootherbug You can have a try with Microsoft Graph Explorer (`https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant={customer's tenant}`). Please note that you need to replace `{customer's tenant}` with the real tenant. Sign in with your CSP admin and call the Graph API. Remember to **Modify permissions** and consent to `Application.ReadWrite.All` if you get 403 error.

Comment: @smootherbug If you want to call Microsoft Graph API in your code, you need to create an Azure AD app manually first. And use this Azure AD app to get the access token by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#:~:text=To%20use%20Microsoft%20Graph%20to,it%20sends%20to%20Microsoft%20Graph. Then you can call Graph API using the access token.

Comment: @smootherbug SDK is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation.

Comment: So There will be a manual step definitely  involved anyways to move the subscription to the admin user of the customer tenant right? This cannot be achieved in a completely automated way. If I understand correctly

Comment: @smootherbug If my answer is clear and helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. That was the confirmation I was looking for.